# Migration from one domain to another - Transfering the social media stats

Tags: social-media, migration, social-networking

I am planning to move my site from one domain to another i.e from domain a.com to b.com . The site also has a lot of content and the migration of content is not an issue. The 301 redirect will take care of all the backlinks also. But my real worry is transfer the social media shares links and stats from domain a.com to b.com.

I need some insight or any way in which the same can be migrated seamlessly from domain a.com to b.com

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter, Facebook and Google+ stats shown in dynamic buttons are all based on your page and site URLs, so if you change the root domain you will lose those statistics, I'm afraid.

You can test it.  Just create a unique page on one domain, pop some buttons in, tweet it, then move the page and see what happens.

Comment: That's what I am fearing also, is there not any way for twitter and FB, G+,linkedin to tellw that the domain has moved so you should reidex this stats for the new domain, like we tell the search egine when we more one domain to another with 301?